# How to redirect ALL output from a command in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, redirection

I'm running Gentoo Linux. A program (`equery`) outputs a massive list of all the currently installed packages (`equery list "*"`). I want to find out which of them are unstable. Equery marks the unstable packages with [ ~] before the package name. The matter is that it only happens when the output is not redirected anywhere - in the terminal. When I try grepping the output (`equery list "*" | grep "~"`) or redirecting it to a file, including stderr (`equery list "*" &> eql.txt`) that information is not redirected - only the names of the packages.

So, how do I redirect ALL the output from a program?

Comment: Is the info still printed to your terminal with `&>` or is it simply no longer printed at all?

Comment: It is not printed at all when redirecting with `&>`.

Comment: OK, then it's not a matter of redirection, the issue is that `equery` detects it is being redirected and modifies its output accordingly. Various commands can do this. Try `equery list "*" 2>&1 | grep "~"` does that work?

Comment: By the way, I answered your original question about list of unstable packages [here](http://superuser.com/a/723701/238539)

Comment: And `equery` will not output `~` without `y` option which you can not combine with `list` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your equery command with [unbuffer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer).

```
unbuffer equery list "*" | grep "-"
```

The unbuffer command makes its argument program think it's connected to a terminal. You may have to add another level of quoting to the `"*"` argument.

Comment: I love the bug on that man page! Lol

Answer (score 1):

`equery -N` turns off pipe detection.

So `equery -N list '*' | grep '~'` should do the job.